# C++ overflow with new keyword debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers

I'm having a tricky debugging issue, perhaps due to my lack of understanding about how c++ manages memory.  The code is too long to post, but the essential setup is as follows:

```
global_var = 0;
int main() {
  for(i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    ClassA a;
    new ClassB(a); // seems to be problem!
  }
}
```

For some `N`, `global_var` gets corrupted (is no longer 0).  There is nothing in the constructors of ClassA or ClassB that mess with `global_var`.

Replacing `new ClassB(a)` with `ClassB b(a)` seems to solve the problem, although this doesn't allow me to do what I want (create a `boost::ptr_vector` with the `new ClassB(a)` instances).

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

**Update:**
I'm really doing something like:

```
global_var = 0;
int main() {
  boost::ptr_vector<ClassB> myobjects;
  for(i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    ClassA a;
    myobjects.push_back(new ClassB(a)); // seems to be problem!
  }
}
```

Both create problems.  But why is this a problem?  Should I be doing something else to put a bunch of objects into a queue?  I'm using `myobjects` it as the basis of a Command Pattern.

**Update**

`classB' looks like:

```
class ClassB {
public:
  ClassB() {}
  ClassB(ClassA a) : a_(a) {}
private:
  ClassA a_;
}
```

ClassA is just a simple list initialization as well (in real life).

Problem?

**Update**
I believe this may have something to do with the fact that global_var is actually a complex matrix type and there may be issues with the way it allocates memory.

Comment: Do you realize the ClassA a goes out of scope and is destroyed by the end of each iteration?

Comment: Yes.  ClassB's constructor copies it into a private variable of ClassB.  I assume this is okay?

Comment: Most likely your constructor for ClassB poses the problem. Could you post this? Apart from that, I really hope that you got this "essential setup" under control, cause the code you posted there is really, _really_ flawed :)

Comment: Posted constructors...  The basic outline is has core similar to Command Pattern.  Need a vector of pointers to command objects.

Comment: What value does global_var have after the execution? Could you do step by step debugging and tell us exactly when its value changes?

Comment: I think you should post ClassA as well.

Comment: Unless your class A is POD, you need to define a copy constructor for it.

Comment: Try checking it with valgrind.

Comment: How do you initialize global_var? Can you post a minimal, fully functional program which exposes your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much exploration, this behavior turned out to be due to a bug in the underlying class of global_var.  There was a subtle bug in the way global and static memory allocation was being done.

Answer (score 2):

Memory in C++ is not automatically freed by default. The result of

```
  new ClassB(a); // seems to be problem!
```

is being created on the heap. The address of the memory is not assigned to anything. Therefore one can't manually delete it like

```
  ClassB* b = new ClassB(a); // creates a B, returns an address,
                             // and stores the address in b.
  delete b;       // deletes memory at address "b"
```

The failure to delete the memory may cause the heap to overflow into other regions of memory in your program, causing your global variable to be overwritten. This could happen without assigning the result of new to a variable, so long as its not deleted.

Comment: A reasonable memory allocator will fail instead of clobbering non heap memory.

Comment: I doubt it would corrupt a global variable (as they usually aren't on the heap), though I may be wrong.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. new() would start to throw bad_alloc if it runs out of memory not start clobbering the address space reserved by globals.

Answer (score 1):

Does classA have a copy constructor?  If so, what does it look like?  If not, create a copy constructor in classA and see if that fixes the problem.

Other than that, try running your code in a debugger and see if you can pin-point when that global changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a bug in one of the two constructors (ClassA or ClassB) which is overwriting the memory of global_var, or corrupting some other memory which eventually causes it to get overwritten.

Comment: My constructors are very simple.  The only thing I'm doing really is copying a into ClassB.  Basically I'm taking a command (Class A) and attaching it to a specific type of executor (Class B).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect something in Class A's copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a data write breakpoint on global_var to find out where it's being written.

In the MSVC debugger, set a breakpoint on the 'for' line. When it gets there, select "New Breakpoint->New Data Breakpoint..." from the Debug menu and enter the &global_var. Continue. The debugger will break the next time the variable is written.

gdb can do this too, but I've forgotten the syntax.